# Using logstash-logback-encoder to log data into elasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-logback-encoder

I want to use logstash-logback-encoder to log the data into elastic search. My configuration follows:

```
<appender name="logstashAppender" class="net.logstash.logback.appender.LogstashTcpSocketAppender">
    <destination>${elasticUrl}</destination>
    <keepAliveDuration>5 minutes</keepAliveDuration>
    <encoder class="net.logstash.logback.encoder.LoggingEventCompositeJsonEncoder">
        <providers>
            <message/>
        </providers>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

However, how do i configure index i want it to be sent into? And according to [git](https://github.com/logstash/logstash-logback-encoder), there is only SSL support, what if my elastic has password authentication?

Is there a way how to add index where the data should be routed?